# Results of MySQL Query limited

Tags: php, mysql, rest, pdo

I try to get a RESTApi with php ans MySQL running and I got pretty far. I'm more a Frontend guy so maybe you can help me figure this out. My code is this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM op_content';
$connection = new PDO(DB_CONN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
$query = $connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

$result = array();

    if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }

        $this->response($this->_toJson($result), 200);
    } else {
        $this->response('', 204);
    }

private function _toJson($data) {
    return is_array($data) ? json_encode($data) : '';
}
```

I dont get any results back from this, only if I add `LIMIT 7` (Limit hast to be <= 7) to the SQL-Query. Are there any server-side limits (working on XAMPP atm) or where can that come from?

**Edit:**
Playing around a little bit I found out that I can return the results as XML (all of them), is there any reason this does not work with json?

Comment: Do you want to ask that `SELECT * FROM op_content LIMIT 7` output nothing while  this returns everything`SELECT * FROM op_content` ?

Comment: No, the other way around. `SELECT * FROM op_content LIMIT 7` returns the first 7 results, as it is supposed to, but `SELECT * FROM op_content` does not return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out. Since I'm from Germany we use umlauts, and altough I got back utf8, somehow it didnt really work, so I had to encode it first.